# Sorting indicators do not appear in customized VDataTable with Vue 3 and Vuetify 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am working on a project and porting the project from Vue 2 to Vue 3 and the same goes for the Vuetify. I am using the latest version of Vuetify and Vue. The current `VDataTable` component in Vuetify comes from Vuetify Labs. The data table works fine, however, the sorting indicators on the table headers do not appear by default as they do in the Vue 2 version of the component.

Here is my template code.

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" outlined>
    <v-toolbar flat dense>
      <v-toolbar-title>
        <span class="subheading">AtomicDEX order book</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
      <v-chip
        class="ma-2"
        outlined
        @click="refreshMarket()"
      >
        <v-icon left>mdi-server-plus</v-icon>Refresh
      </v-chip>
    </v-toolbar>
    <div v-if="marketdata.asks">
      <div>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex md lg>
            <v-card-title>Asks</v-card-title>
            <div class="table-container">
            <v-data-table
              dense
              :sort-by="sortBy"
              :headers="asksHeaders"
              :items="marketdata.asks"
              :rows-per-page="-1"
              options="disablePagination"
              class="elevation-1"
            >
              <template v-slot:column.price="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }}) 
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.maxvolume="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Amount ({{wallets.base.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.relamount="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Total ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <!-- Rounding from https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/ -->
              <!-- Better to move to computed function for maintainability/non-repetitive -->
              <template v-slot:item.price="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.price2="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
  <!-- Remaining code -->

<!--
better implementation handled in parent component on load of orders, then promise to set flag
                <v-chip v-if="hasMyOrder(item.price)" color="purple" dark>me</v-chip>
-->
                <v-chip v-if="item.myOrder" x-small color="purple" dark>*</v-chip>
              </template> 

              <template v-slot:item.maxvolume="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.maxvolume) }}
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.relamount="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price * item.columns.maxvolume) }}
              </template>
              <template v-slot:bottom></template>
            </v-data-table>
            </div>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>No current asks to display.</div>
    <h2 class="pl-3">{{ middlePriceSpreadData.middle }} Middle Price (Spread: {{ middlePriceSpreadData.spread}} %)</h2>

    <div v-if="marketdata.bids">
      <div>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex md lg>
            <v-card-title>Bids</v-card-title>
            <div class="table-container">
            <v-data-table
               dense
              :sort-by="sortBy"
              :disable-pagination="true"
              :headers="bidsHeaders"
              :items="marketdata.bids"
              :items-per-page="-1"
            >

              <template v-slot:column.price="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.baseamount="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Amount ({{wallets.base.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.maxvolume="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Total ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <!-- Rounding from https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/ -->
              <!-- Better to move to computed function for maintainability/non-repetitive -->
              <template v-slot:item.price="{ item }">
                  {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
              </template>
              
              <!-- For highlighting my orders, TODO need a price:uuid array before grouping by price in AppTraderview   -->
              <template v-slot:item.price2="{ item }">
                  {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
<!--
better implementation in parent component
                <v-chip v-if="hasMyOrder(item.price)" color="purple" dark>me</v-chip>
-->
                <v-chip v-if="item.myOrder" x-small dark>*</v-chip>
              </template> 
              <template
                v-slot:item.baseamount="{ item }"
              >{{ roundedPrice(item.columns.maxvolume / item.columns.price) }}</template>
              <template
                v-slot:item.maxvolume="{ item }"
              >{{ roundedPrice(item.columns.maxvolume) }}</template>
              <template v-slot:bottom></template>
            </v-data-table>
            </div>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>No current bids to display.</div>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Here is the script section of my code:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'

export default {
  name: "MarketData",
  props: ['wallets', 'marketdata', 'myOrdersThisMarket'],
  components: {
    VDataTable
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      cexprice: "",
      myOrders: "",
      takerDialog: false,
      makerDialog: false,
      activeCoins: [],
      walletBalance: { base: 0, rel: 0 },
      trade: { base: "", rel: "", price: "", amount: "0" },
      appName: "MarketData",
      customerrors: [],
      // sortBy: ['price'],
      // sortDesc: [false],
      sortBy: [{ key: '[price]', order: 'desc' }],
      asksHeaders: [
        {
          title: "Price (rel)",
          align: "left",
          sortable: true,
          key: "price"
        },
        { title: "Amount (base)", align: "left", key: "maxvolume" },
        { title: "Total (rel))", align: "right", key: "relamount" }
      ],
      bidsHeaders: [
        {
          title: "Price (rel)",
          align: "left",
          sortable: true,
          key: "price"
        },
        { title: "Base Amount", align: "left", key: "baseamount" },
        { title: "Can Cancel", align: "right", key: "maxvolume" }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    refreshMarket: function() {
      this.$emit("refresh-market")
    },
    objectArrayByKeys: function(obj) {
      let toArray = [];
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        toArray.push(obj[key]);
      });
      return toArray;
    },
    hasMyOrder: function(price){
      return this.myOrdersThisMarket.find(x => x.price == price)
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    console.log(this.appName + " Created");
    // original prod code
//    this.showDEXMarket(this.wallets.base.ticker, this.wallets.rel.ticker)
    // working fake data
    // this.marketdata = this.fakeData
    // test grouping
    // this.marketdata.asks = this.groupByPrice2(this.fakeData.asks, "price");
    // this.marketdata.bids = this.groupByPrice2(this.fakeData.bids, "price");
    //this.getCEXprice(this.wallets.base.ticker, this.wallets.rel.ticker);
    console.log(this.appName + " Finished Created");
  },
  computed: {
    coinCount: function() {
      return this.activeCoins.length;
    },
    roundedPrice() {
        return price => {
          return Number((Math.round(price * 1e8) / 1e8).toFixed(8))
        }
      },
    middlePriceSpreadData: function(lowAsk, highBid) {
      // middlePriceSpreadData.middle & middlePriceSpreadData.spread
      let middlePriceSpreadData = {}
      middlePriceSpreadData.middle = "No"
      middlePriceSpreadData.spread = 0
      if( this.marketdata.asks === undefined || this.marketdata.bids === undefined){
        return middlePriceSpreadData
      }
      if( this.marketdata.asks.length > 0 && this.marketdata.bids.length > 0) {
        let lowestAsk = this.marketdata.asks.sort((a,b) => a.price - b.price)[0].price 
        let highestBid = this.marketdata.bids.sort((a,b) => b.price - a.price)[0].price
        let spread = (parseFloat(lowestAsk) - parseFloat(highestBid))
        let middle = parseFloat(parseFloat(highestBid) + (parseFloat(lowestAsk) - parseFloat(highestBid))/2)
        middlePriceSpreadData.middle = middle.toFixed(8) + " Approx. "
        middlePriceSpreadData.spread = (parseFloat(spread/middle) * 100).toFixed(1)
        return middlePriceSpreadData 
      }
      else {
        return middlePriceSpreadData
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting indicators are part of the default column v-slot. When you use your own v-slot, you erase everything that was there by default. If you customize the column header, you will need to re-implement the sorting arrows manually.

From what I can gather from the v-data-table [API documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots) and inspecting the CSS of normal columns, the v-slot code below will recreate the default column header with working sorting icons for a column named "Price"

```html
<template v-slot:column.price="{ column, getSortIcon, toggleSort }">
  <div class="v-data-table-header__content">
    <span>Price</span>
    <v-icon
      class="v-data-table-header__sort-icon"
      :icon="getSortIcon(column)"
      @click="toggleSort(column)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Use this as your starting v-slot code for your different columns and customize however you see fit.

[Vuetify Playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) (reproducing default "Calories" column)

---

##### Update #1

Example of updating your first column...

Change this:

```html
<template v-slot:column.price="{ header }">
  <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
  Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }}) 
</template>
```

To this:

```html
<template v-slot:column.price="{ column, getSortIcon, toggleSort }">
  <div class="v-data-table-header__content">
    <span>Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }}) </span>
    <v-icon
      class="v-data-table-header__sort-icon"
      :icon="getSortIcon(column)"
      @click="toggleSort(column)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Notice for this column you only have to update what is in the `<span>`. For other columns you'll need to also update the name in `v-slot:column.price` with the correct column name.

---

##### Update #2

It seems the only way I can possibly make sense is if I write the entirety of the template code for you to copy/paste into your app, so here you go:

```html
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" outlined>
    <v-toolbar flat dense>
      <v-toolbar-title>
        <span class="subheading">AtomicDEX order book</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
      <v-chip
        class="ma-2"
        outlined
        @click="refreshMarket()"
      >
        <v-icon left>mdi-server-plus</v-icon>Refresh
      </v-chip>
    </v-toolbar>
    <div v-if="marketdata.asks">
      <div>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex md lg>
            <v-card-title>Asks</v-card-title>
            <div class="table-container">
            <v-data-table
              dense
              :sort-by="sortBy"
              :headers="asksHeaders"
              :items="marketdata.asks"
              :rows-per-page="-1"
              options="disablePagination"
              class="elevation-1"
            >
              <template v-slot:column.price="{ column, getSortIcon, toggleSort }">
                <div class="v-data-table-header__content">
                  <span>Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }}) </span>
                  <v-icon
                    class="v-data-table-header__sort-icon"
                    :icon="getSortIcon(column)"
                    @click="toggleSort(column)"
                  />
                </div>
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.maxvolume="{ column, getSortIcon, toggleSort }">
                <div class="v-data-table-header__content">
                  <span>Amount ({{wallets.base.ticker }})</span>
                  <v-icon
                    class="v-data-table-header__sort-icon"
                    :icon="getSortIcon(column)"
                    @click="toggleSort(column)"
                  />
                </div>
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.relamount="{ column, getSortIcon, toggleSort }">
                <div class="v-data-table-header__content">
                  <span>Total ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})</span>
                  <v-icon
                    class="v-data-table-header__sort-icon"
                    :icon="getSortIcon(column)"
                    @click="toggleSort(column)"
                  />
                </div>
              </template>

              <!-- Rounding from https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/ -->
              <!-- Better to move to computed function for maintainability/non-repetitive -->
              <template v-slot:item.price="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.price2="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
  <!-- Remaining code -->

<!--
better implementation handled in parent component on load of orders, then promise to set flag
                <v-chip v-if="hasMyOrder(item.price)" color="purple" dark>me</v-chip>
-->
                <v-chip v-if="item.myOrder" x-small color="purple" dark>*</v-chip>
              </template> 

              <template v-slot:item.maxvolume="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.maxvolume) }}
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.relamount="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price * item.columns.maxvolume) }}
              </template>
              <template v-slot:bottom></template>
            </v-data-table>
            </div>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>No current asks to display.</div>
    <h2 class="pl-3">{{ middlePriceSpreadData.middle }} Middle Price (Spread: {{ middlePriceSpreadData.spread}} %)</h2>

    <div v-if="marketdata.bids">
      <div>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex md lg>
            <v-card-title>Bids</v-card-title>
            <div class="table-container">
            <v-data-table
               dense
              :sort-by="sortBy"
              :disable-pagination="true"
              :headers="bidsHeaders"
              :items="marketdata.bids"
              :items-per-page="-1"
            >
              <template v-slot:column.price="{ column, getSortIcon, toggleSort }">
                <div class="v-data-table-header__content">
                  <span>Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }}) </span>
                  <v-icon
                    class="v-data-table-header__sort-icon"
                    :icon="getSortIcon(column)"
                    @click="toggleSort(column)"
                  />
                </div>
              </template>
              
              <template v-slot:column.baseamount="{ column, getSortIcon, toggleSort }">
                <div class="v-data-table-header__content">
                  <span>Amount ({{wallets.base.ticker }})</span>
                  <v-icon
                    class="v-data-table-header__sort-icon"
                    :icon="getSortIcon(column)"
                    @click="toggleSort(column)"
                  />
                </div>
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.maxvolume="{ column, getSortIcon, toggleSort }">
                <div class="v-data-table-header__content">
                  <span>Total ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})</span>
                  <v-icon
                    class="v-data-table-header__sort-icon"
                    :icon="getSortIcon(column)"
                    @click="toggleSort(column)"
                  />
                </div>
              </template>

              <!-- Rounding from https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/ -->
              <!-- Better to move to computed function for maintainability/non-repetitive -->
              <template v-slot:item.price="{ item }">
                  {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
              </template>
              
              <!-- For highlighting my orders, TODO need a price:uuid array before grouping by price in AppTraderview   -->
              <template v-slot:item.price2="{ item }">
                  {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
<!--
better implementation in parent component
                <v-chip v-if="hasMyOrder(item.price)" color="purple" dark>me</v-chip>
-->
                <v-chip v-if="item.myOrder" x-small dark>*</v-chip>
              </template> 
              <template
                v-slot:item.baseamount="{ item }"
              >{{ roundedPrice(item.columns.maxvolume / item.columns.price) }}</template>
              <template
                v-slot:item.maxvolume="{ item }"
              >{{ roundedPrice(item.columns.maxvolume) }}</template>
              <template v-slot:bottom></template>
            </v-data-table>
            </div>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>No current bids to display.</div>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

---

#### Update #3

[here is your v-data-table](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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), isolated from the rest of your code, with working sort icons.

Comment: Does not work I have tried something like this 
`   <template v-slot:column.price="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }}) 
                <v-icon
                  class="v-data-table-header__sort-icon"
                 :icon="getSortIcon(column)"
                 @click="sortBy"
                 />
              </template>`

Comment: What you tried is not what I gave in my answer. Check my Playground link... **it works**.  You need _everything_ written in my answer to get just the **default** functionality.  If you remove things, of course it will break.  For example, I'm not sure why you changed the v-slot props to `"{ header }"` as `header` is not a valid v-slot property (check the docs!) and you don't even use it in your slot, so what is it's purpose?  Also, see how the v-icon in my code uses `getSortIcon`? I pass it in as a v-slot prop. That's where it comes from... Don't remove it from the props

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an actual example of how to update the code for **one** of your columns.  Hopefully you can handle the others

Comment: Still does not work, nothing breaks if I remove the header slot, However your code does not display the data table entirely, is it because of the classes I should let you know that vdatatable is being used by importing it from vuetify labs

Comment: Please understand that my code is just what is necessary to fix your table. It's not meant to "display the data table entirely".  **Your header v-slot templates are whats wrong with your code.  My code shows the correct way to write them, (and only them)**.  You might be misunderstanding that they aren't even "header" v-slots, they are column slots. There are no slots that use "{ header }"` as their v-slot props.  All those slots you have with `"{ header }"` in them should be `"{ column, getSortIcon, toggleSort }"` instead, and written like how they are in my answer.

Comment: I have made yet another update to my answer with the **entire** template code updated.  All of the `column` v-slots have been rewritten correctly. I thought by providing an example of only one correct v-slot the rest could be easily done without me, but it was not to be. I have now rewritten **all** of them and even included the rest of the template code so all you will need to do is copy/paste the whole thing and not think about it.

Comment: I am really sorry to bother you but I followed your steps entirely and copy pasted my code, the vdatatable has now vanished entirely. You can have a look here.

http://v3dev.komodefi.com:17077/traderview/KMD/BTC

[link] This is the heading of the widget displaying the vdatatable.
0.00000873 Approx. Middle Price (Spread: 4.3 %) with my previous code

I have update my question and added the script section as well.

Comment: I don't know what the problem could be, but I don't see the table missing (AtomicDEX order book?).  It's way too much code and too many unknown variables/props I have no clue about.  When isolated, your v-data-table works fine.  I unequivocally proved in my original answer how to add working sort icons to the v-data-table column v-slots using the most simple v-data-table example possible.  Given a more complicated table, the column v-slot code does not and should not change or affect anything outside of itself.  **Something else** is wrong with your table, page, or Vuetify config.

Comment: Updated answer with link at the bottom to your exact v-data-table code with working sort icons.

Comment: I do the exact same thing but this time it disappears my entire data table on the component

Comment: I can't help with that.  I've done everything except run your entire app.  Your original question is about getting sort icons working on v-data-table columns.  I think we're well past that.

Comment: If you narrow down what the issue might be, let me know.  There's some implementation detail unique to your app interfering with the rendering.  Could be a bug completely unrelated to the table.  You need to isolate what the issue or problem code is.  I probably can't help with debugging that unless I had your whole app.

Comment: Indeed https://github.com/iamahmedshahh/mm2v3

Comment: I find it difficult to believe it was somehow working with your previous "header" v-slots, and then changing it to the correct v-slot code somehow caused the entire table not to render?  If you change it back does it somehow work again?

Comment: I ran your code, fixed all your API calls which used `process.env` which is incorrect in a Vite app (should use [import.meta.env](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html)), and when I load the page for `http://localhost:5173/traderview/KMD/BTC`, your v-data-tabe with my columns slots... [just works](https://i.imgur.com/Q7BQpDf.png).   ONLY other code change was to comment out `this.updateBalances()` in DashboardWalletInfo.vue because it was ridiculously causing thousands of non-stop networks calls.

Comment: At this point, the problem seems somewhere on your end.  Besides coming over to your house and running the code with you there's nothing else I can do. This question stopped being about how to add working sort icons to v-data-table columns a long time ago. That specific question is **solved**